# Is the reverse of Liouville's theorem true?

Tags: hamiltonian-formalism, hamiltonian, phase-space

Liouville's theorem states phase space volume is conserved for Hamiltonian systems. Given a general dynamical system, if it is shown to have conserved phase space volume, will it also have a Hamiltonian? Are there any known counterexamples if not true?

Comment: It seems to me that you are confused about some concepts. Phase space (canonical momentum and generalized coordinate) is only defined when the Hamiltonian is defined..

Comment: @K.R.Park Really? The way I thought it went is that the phase space is just the cotangent bundle of the configuration space, and the hamiltonian is just one of many interesting real-valued functions one can use.

Comment: Oh, or maybe the point is that the **volume** is inextricably linked with the hamiltonian.  In that case I would agree.

Comment: The idea of phase space volume contracting and expanding is very general. For a generic dynamical system, the rate of contraction is given by the sum of the Lyapunov exponents. Maybe a more general way of asking my question is that to ask if the sum of the Lyapunov exponents being zero is equivalent to the system being hamiltonian, at least for even dimensional systems.

Comment: As it turns out though, any divergence-free dynamical system satisfied Liouville's theorem as explained [here](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Hamiltonian_systems#Liouville.27s_Theorem), so I think Hamiltonian systems are just a subset of all dynamical systems that satisfy this quality.